# php is assigning last result to all array keys

Tags: php, arrays

There is some problem, the code below assigning the last pr_name to all keys.

```
$arr   = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 
$keys[] = $row['pr_code'];
$items = array_fill_keys($keys, $row['pr_name']);
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what `array_fill_keys` does, it's used to fill an array with the same value throughout. It's only for very specific uses (such as "resetting" an array with zeros, for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply with this:

```
$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 
  $items[$row['pr_code']] = $row['pr_name'];
}
```